# Autounattend.xml for custom install.wim (Windows 7 based)

Tags: windows-7, unattended

I've created a custom install.wim for my Windows 7 installations. It works just fine if I go through the install wizard manually. As soon as I add a "autounattend.xml" file to my install medium I get this error "There are no installation copy's available" in the screen where you normally have the choice to install "Home, Ultimate, ...".

I Suppose the problem is somewhere in my autounattend.xml file, maybe here ?

```
<InstallFrom>
<MetaData wcm:action="add">
<Key>/IMAGE/INDEX</Key>
<Value>1</Value>
</MetaData>
</InstallFrom>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It’s easy to check the indexes on your image with DISM (Deployment Image Servicing and Management). 
From an elevated command prompt, type “DISM /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:d:\sources\install.wim”. Don’t use the quotes and change the path to the location of your .wim image. This command and the output are discussed in the TechNet article ‘[Best Practices for Image Deployment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799255(v=ws.10).aspx)’, in the section titled ‘Selecting the Windows Image to Install During Windows Setup’ (about half way down the page). I also found the DISM command and several XML examples on the [MetaData](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff716384.aspx) page of the Unattended Windows Setup Reference on TechNet.

More deployment related articles and videos can be found on the [Deliver and Deploy Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/dd641427.aspx) page of the Springboard Series on TechNet

Hope this helps.